# C Header with bits names for LPC1768

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm, header

I'm starting with ARM and I program in C for LPC1768.

I included "LPC17xx.h". It gives registers names in C. But where are the names of bits?

For instance: I want to use UART. So first step: "*In the PCONP register (Table46), set bits PCUART2*".

Now I'm doing it this way: `LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << 24);`

But I want to do it this way: `LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << PCUART2)`

Now I have to look into lots of tables to see what are the numbers of bits. Is there any C header file that has all the definitions? Something like that: `#define PCUART2 24` or similar.

(I know there are high level libraries with functions like "init_uart()" but I have to write it low)

Comment: If you can't find a header, just write it out.  Can't take that long, and you only need to do it once.

Comment: I know I can write it :) I'm looking for it to save work, writing it from zero won't save me any time.

And it would take long to go through all the tables..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found anwser on another site. With this help, I created single header with defines. You can download it there: http://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/viewtopic.php?p=14606647#14606647